# Limit columns to certain width in MySQL command

Tags: mysql

The `mysql` command gives nice tabular outputs that take into consideration half and full width spacing.

For example:

```
> select 'The quick brown fox jumps over the' text union select '０１２３４５６７８９０';
+------------------------------------+
| text                               |
+------------------------------------+
| The quick brown fox jumps over the |
| ０１２３４５６７８９０             |
+------------------------------------+
2 rows in set
```

Given this, how do I truncate a column to a certain width?

e.g. How do I get this?

```
+----------------+
| text           |
+----------------+
| The quick brow |
| ０１２３４５６ |
+----------------+
```

**Edit:** In terms of what I've tried.

If I attempt this by changing the query to use something like `LEFT()`:

```
> select left(text, 7) text from (select 'The quick brown fox jumps over the' text union select '０１２３４５６７８９０') x;
+-----------------------+
| text                  |
+-----------------------+
| The qui               |
| ０１２３４５６        |
+-----------------------+
2 rows in set
```

What I get isn't exactly what I wanted. I don't want 7 left characters of each string, I want both strings to show as many characters as optimally fit into a given width.  I want a result similar to what's under "e.g. How do I get this?", if say this width was 14 (half-width characters).

MySQL does cope with different widths, as the first example establishes. (Look at it with a monospaced editor and the pipes line up.) Any solution like SQL Plus' `column foo format a10`, or using `ENCODE()` and `BIT_LENGTH()`, or user functions could work. The lack of answers probably means there isn't an easy solution?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a character set issue. Here is why:

I ran

```
select left(text, 7) text from
(select 'The quick brown fox jumps over the' text union select '０１２３４５６７８９０') x;
```

in MySQL 5.6.22 for Windows. Here is that output

```
+---------+
| text    |
+---------+
| The qui |
| ??????? |
+---------+
```

Same query in MySQL 5.6.21 for CentOS 6.3

```
+-----------------------+
| text                  |
+-----------------------+
| The qui               |
| ０１２３４５６        |
+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You should use the CAST operator

```
select left(CONVERT(text USING latin1), 7) text from
(select 'The quick brown fox jumps over the' text union select '01234567890') x;
```

When I ran this in MySQL 5.6.22 for Windows, I got this

```
+---------+
| text    |
+---------+
| The qui |
| ??????? |
+---------+
```

When I ran this in MySQL 5.6.21 for CentOS 6.3, I got the same thing

```
+---------+
| text    |
+---------+
| The qui |
| ??????? |
+---------+
```

Just hunt down the correct character set.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
select substring('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',1,14 )text 
union select substring('0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0',1,13) ;
```